# vmware workstation all options grayed out

Tags: vmware-workstation, access-control

I made a Windows 11 machine with access control and TPM module. (I followed [this](https://www.ictpower.it/sistemi-operativi/installare-una-vm-windows-11-con-vmware-workstation.htm) guide, the only difference is that I don't have 'Workstation Beta' option and used 16.2.
Windows 11 works fine but now I cannot edit settings, everything is grayed out both when the machine is powered or not.

When I power off the VM and I click on it I'm asked for access control password, even after this everything is grayed, I cannot change RAM, CPU or add network interface, nothing.

What am I doing wrong?

My Workstation version is 16.2.4 build-20089737

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that the VM is powered off and is not suspended?

Comment: Yes, but I now saw, on the greyed panel of settings, that machine is in a lock state. I searched for .lck folder, deleted and could change everything. i'm dumb! haha